# Except Python codec errors?

Tags: python, decode, encode

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.1/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 805: invalid start byte
```

Hi, I get this exception. How do I catch it, and continue reading my files when I get this exception.

My program has a loop that reads a text file line-by-line and tries to do some processing. However, some files I encounter may not be text files, or have lines that are not properly formatted (foreign language etc). I want to ignore those lines.

The following is not working

```
for line in sys.stdin:
   if line != "":
      try:
         matched = re.match(searchstuff, line, re.IGNORECASE)
         print (matched)
      except UnicodeDecodeError, UnicodeEncodeError:
         continue
```

Comment: There's an entire **CHAPTER** in the Python tutorial *dedicated* to errors and exceptions. Try there. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Yeah, I get it. I'm not asking whether Python has features related to errors and exceptions. I am using try, except statements, but these codec decode errors are not getting excepted, resulting in failed jobs.

Comment: Please post short, but unedited code. Are the ** literally in your code?

Comment: phihag: no they're not. I just wanted to emphasize. now removed

Comment: How do you know that your try block is even where the error happens?

Comment: I've posted the snippet. Here's the scenario. I might get random files (languages other than english) in my data dump - and even images.

Comment: You've posted the snippet, but you haven't posted the traceback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/codecs.html. When you open the codecs stream, you probably want to use the additional argument `errors='ignore'`

In Python 3, `sys.stdin` is by default opened as a text stream (see http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html), and has strict error checking.

You need to reopen it as an error-tolerant utf-8 stream. Something like this will work:

```
sys.stdin = codecs.getreader('utf8')(sys.stdin.detach(), errors='ignore')
```

Comment: He's running 3.1, so not *quite* this.

Comment: @Ignacio good point, but the answer is the same - I fixed the link to the py3k docs.

Comment: Not... quite. `codecs.open()` isn't really needed in 3.x, since its capabilities are now a part of `open()`.

Comment: I'm not calling codec.open() or any function in the codec module. I think it's getting called by re.search()

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, the problems are caused because sys.stdin is opened as an error-intolerant utf-8 stream by default in py3k. I've patched my answer.